# Inequality clarification

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Does $1 < |z| < 2$ imply $|\frac{1}{z}| < 1$?

This is what I tried:

Divide given inequality by 2:
$\frac{1}{2} < |\frac{z}{2}| < 1$

Apply reciprocal operation:
${2} > |\frac{2}{z}| > 1$

Divide by 2:
$1 > |\frac{1}{z}| > \frac{1}{2}$

Hence, $|\frac{1}{z}| < 1$

Did I get that correct?

Comment: Just divide $1 < |z|$ by $|z|$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the conclusion is true. Visually, we can see:

[image]

The graph of $y=\left |\frac{1}{x} \right |$ is in purple, and the region where $1 < |x| < 2$ is shaded in red. We can see that the value of $\left |\frac{1}{x} \right |$ is certainly less than $1$ in the red region.

Comment: Quite insightful and presents one more way to understand the concept. thank you!